# javascript confirm box shows unwanted message

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to show a confirm box. I see "this site says" in the alert. How can I remove that text? I don't want to use Jquery UI library.

```
var r = confirm("Press a button");
if (r == true) {
    x = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

Comment: You can not do that.

Comment: You can't. It's for anti-phishing

Comment: To avoid that you can create custom Modal popup